# How to auto-update multiple sheets in Excel workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets - "Upcoming Orders" and "Completed Orders". I used "Upcoming Orders" sheet for upcoming orders, and "Completed Orders" for completed orders.

Once the order is completed, I delete it from "Upcoming Orders" sheet and paste it into "Completed Orders".

Is there a way to automate it by creating a macro that would do it it automatically for me, once I mark order as completed in the "Upcoming Orders" sheet it will be automatically add into the " Completed Orders" sheet.

I went over a few tutorial on macros, but I couldn't find the right method. Please help.

Comment: Assuming there is something you update in the data on the "Upcoming Orders" sheet that identifies that it is now completed, you could use a `Worksheet_Change` event.  Give it a try and let us know if you have any specific problems you need help with.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Both spreadsheets are have the same columns and headers. I just remove a record from one sheet and paste it to another one. It's always the last record(row). How can I use Worksheet_Change to do that?

Comment: Assuming there is something in that last record that you update when the order is completed (e.g. maybe you change column X in that row to say "complete", or maybe you enter a date into column G, or anything similar), just create a `Worksheet_Change` event and, if the `Target` is in the relevant row and column, run the code to move the row to the other sheet.  There are plenty of examples all over Stack Overflow and the rest of the internet, so give it a try and let us know if you have any specific problems you need help with.

Comment: Thank you for a hint! I found a solution that works. I would like to add one more feature to my spreadsheet. There is a column "Documents", for every record a cell contains 2 checkboxes that I check to indicate which documents have been executed for this order. When I add a new row, I have to copy and paste these checkboxes again. Is there a way to replicate them automatically when I insert/add a new row?

Comment: what you are doing is not a good design, you have to keep one sheet and only one sheet for all of your transactions and then get reports based on what you want. For example, there should be a column like "date order completed" once that column is filled that means that order has been completed. You can simply use an Excel table and use its autofilters to filter and show only the ones that have a completion date or write a macro that lists the orders that have a completion date, or the orders that are needed to be completed, this way you can have a lot more control

Answer (score 0):

*How about double click, With double click on single cell you can copy the row to "Completed Orders" Sheet and delete it from "Upcoming Orders"*

*Example [Workbook.SheetBeforeDoubleClick Event (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-sheetbeforedoubleclick-event-excel)*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sht As Object, _
                                            ByVal Target As Range, _
                                                  Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RngCopy As Range
    Dim Target_Sht As Worksheet

    Cancel = True

    Set Target_Sht = Sheets("Completed Orders")

    Set RngCopy = Sht.Range("A" & Target.Row, Sht.Cells _
                           (Target.Row, Sht.UsedRange.Column + _
                            Sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address)

    With Target_Sht
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        RngCopy.Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        Sht.Rows(Target.Row).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I'm new to this website, so this is my first "answer"
I am also new to VBA coding, but I am hitting it hard xD*

I simply made a macro that opens an "inputbox" to enter a sale ID#, "OK" then moves it from it's location in the "Upcoming Orders" table to the first row of the "Completed Orders" table on the second sheet... I think this is nice because it allows you to verify the data which you are transferring by having to actually type the ID#; also makes it easier for longer tables since you wouldn't have to search for the entry. 
(tomorrow I will try to make one that returns records to the "Upcoming" page... in case a mistake was made.
-Enjoy! (.Reverus.)

```
Sub Record_Transfer()
  Dim Rcrd, Rcrd2, Rng, tbl1, Tbl2 As Range
  Dim IDnum As String
  Dim x, x2, y, n As Integer

Worksheets(1).Activate

Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

IDnum = InputBox("Input ID to transfer: ", ["Transfer"], 17)
    If vbOKCancel = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If vbOKCancel = vbOK Then
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Range
        Set Rcrd = Rng.Find(IDnum, LookIn:=xlValues)
     End If

     If Rcrd Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "ID not found."
             Exit Sub
     End If

 y = Rcrd.Row
 Set Rcrd = Worksheets(1).Range(Rcrd, Rcrd.End(xlToRight))
 x2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns.Count

 Worksheets(2).Activate
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add (1)
 Set Rcrd2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListRows(1).Range
     For x = 1 To x2
         Rcrd2.Cells(x).Value = Rcrd.Cells(x).Value
         If x > x2 Then GoTo Del
     Next x
 Del:
     Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Rows(y).Delete

 End Sub
```

Comment: btw, my macro would need to be assigned to a button (I called mine ... "Transfer")